# What does voltage range mean in this LED driver?

Tags: voltage, led, switch-mode-power-supply, led-driver

Many types of LED drivers have an output voltage range and not an exactly regulated voltage. I asked the seller and he said that this means it is suitable for all power LEDs that work with a voltage range between 60 to 90 V, but I wonder, how can this LED driver understand how much voltage your LED needs? I already tested the open circuit voltage and it was more than 100 V.

[image]

Comment: 60-90 V is the _compliance voltage_ range. Google it.

Answer (score 7):

LEDs work best if you drive them with a **current**.

When you would apply a voltage to a LED or a string of LEDs in series, the current can vary a lot over production lots and temperature. It is very well possible that **too much current** will flow through the LEDs which makes them hot and limit their lifetime.

So it is better to drive LEDs with a **current**.

Such a LED driver module does just that. It adapts the **voltage** such that the specified **300mA** current flows. It can adjust the voltage between 60 and 90 V DC in order to achieve that.

So as long as you would use LEDs in a configuration (series/parallel) that  they should be powered at between 60 and 90 V at 300 mA, (20 - 30 W) then this module is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constant current 300 mA driver where output voltage would vary depending upon the load or wattage which is 25 to 36 watts MCPC module. Thus it is intelligent enough to adapt its voltages without altering the output current. As LED is sensitive to current flow, its important to maintain the constant current flow depending upon the total resistance of the circuit to avoid overheating and destruction of the MCPC module.

Comment: MCPC? What’s that?